# How to create interactive javascript representation of a python object in Jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have python code that end up producing rather complex objects. I often use this code in Jupyter notebooks. I would like to have a an interactive javascript representation of this complex object in a notebook cell that would allow me to inspect various properties of the object graphically.

I suppose that [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html#What-are-widgets?) might be interesting in this context.
Here is another nice [example](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/).

My ultimate goal is to try to connect an object's representation to an interactive image like [this](http://angularplasmid.vixis.com/index.php) one.

I understand that this question is open ended, but I would like to know if there is a simple example around for these requirements. Specifically, how to connect something that depends on AngularJS to one of the custom **repr** methods that Jupyter supports?

EDIT:

I have done some investigation and I have created a MyCircle [class](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BjornFJohansson/pydna/blob/py3dev/scripts/circle/circle.ipynb) that has a javascript representation. The link goes to a Jupyter notebook.

What is missing for me is probably a direction where to go. There is a myriad of javascript libraries out there and I would rather use one instead of reinventing the wheel.

I would like to have generated plot consisting of boxes that could be clicked and where each box gives access to some property of th undelying python object. I feel that someone has done this already, but I am looking in the wrong places.

Comment: I have done some investigation and I have created a MyCircle [class](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BjornFJohansson/pydna/blob/py3dev/scripts/circle/circle.ipynb) that has a javascript representation. What is missing is probably a direction where to go. There is a myriad of javascript libraries out there and I would rather use one instead of reinventing the wheel.